# Why does my whole array have '\0'?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, data-structures, structure

This is causing a lot of issues for my program. Whys is it when I create a new array of structured pointers that they all equal to `'\0'`? I checked if they are at the end of the array `if(table_p -> buckets_array[i] == '\0'){ printf("ask this \n") ; }` and it is true for every member of the array. Am I checking it wrong? Shouldn't only the last member have `\0`?

```
typedef struct data_{
  char *key;
  void *data;
  struct data_ *next;
}data_el;

typedef struct hash_table_ {
  void **order;
  int *number_next_calls;
  int *number_buckets;
  int *buckets_size;
  int *worst;
  int *total;
  float *average;
  int (*hash_func)(char *);
  int (*comp_func)(void*, void*);
  data_el **buckets_array;
} hash_table, *Phash_table;

/*Create buckets array*/
table_p -> buckets_array = (data_el **)malloc(sizeof(data_el *)*(size+1));
table_p -> buckets_size = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*(size+1));

/*Setting order array*/
  table_p -> order = NULL;

/*Setting inital condictions*/
table_p -> worst = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
table_p -> total = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
table_p -> average = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float));
table_p -> number_buckets = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));

/*This is where I have isssue*/
for(i = 0; i < size; i++){
    table_p -> buckets_array[i] = NULL;
    table_p -> buckets_array[i] -> buckets_size = 0;

    if(table_p -> buckets_array[i] == '\0'){
      printf("ask this \n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Would it help if I said that `NULL` is exactly the same as `\0`? So if you do `buckets_array[i] = NULL;` then yes, `buckets_array[i] == '\0'` after that.

Comment: Yes that would really answer my questions. thanks

Comment: OK. Well, they're not truly exactly the same, they have different types. But the same value!

Comment: the "final member is '\0'" convention only applies to strings, as a "string" in C is only an array of characters terminated by '\0'. Break that down, and what you get is that the single-quotes mean you're specifying a character, but the backslash means escape it as a character and use the value of 0; so you could say (and I've seen, to my horror) "mychar = 0" and get the same effect, but lose important contextual clues for the reader.

Comment: @tbert Yes, C is really far too lenient with that. You can even write `mychar = 45.6;` without errors or warnings. Not nice for beginners.

Comment: @MrLister meh, i find it freeing to be able to do things like that, and a challenge to the craftsman to do the right thing given a multitude of options; if you want a language that cans datatypes for you, you shouldn't be working in C, IMO.

Comment: @tbert I like C a lot. But as much as I hate C#, there are some things C# does right which C bungles up, and I feel this is one of them. You shouldn't be able to assign things that cause data loss, without warning even at the highest warning level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, you have:

```
table_p -> buckets_array[i] = NULL;
table_p -> buckets_array[i] -> buckets_size = 0;
```

That is like saying:

```
table_p -> buckets_array[i] = NULL;
NULL -> buckets_size = 0;
```

which is not good.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(table_p -> buckets_array[i] == '\0'){
```

I already pointed out in your previous (very similar) post, that `table_p->buckets_array[i]` is of type "pointer to data_el", and that '\0' is an integer constant. Please read before you post.